# Magento: Emailing checkout contents instead of payment

Tags: email, magento, module, payment, checkout

I'm looking for a way  in magento to, when going through the checkout, it bypasses payments and instead sends the clients order and other information via an email to the companies email address so that they can get in touch with the customer directly BEFORE any payments. So that it can all be done over the phone.

To simplify, i need to have a workflow like this:

1. User goes to checkout
2. User confirms order
3. Order is emailed to site email
4. company gets in touch with customer
5. order confirmed over the phone, and customer goes through with payment.

I just need a starting point. I've seen a lot of topics on making your own payment modules but I'm not sure if that's the right way to go about this.

Comment: A custom payment module would be a part of this, it would let you accept an order without doing any authorize/capture on the payment method.  A payment module will do nothing to build you the UI/process to handle walking the customer through the rest of their order on the phone.

Comment: It'll be fine. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a new payment module, which would not ask for any payment information, but simply move the checkout process along the line. Make this the only enabled payment provider.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. At least i know i was thinking along the right lines. I'm really susprised i got 2 answers so quickly :)